# Visa to search for job in Singapore

Tags: working-visas, singapore

I am from India and having good experience in my job profile - **QA [Software + Web testing + Mobile app testing]**. I have heard that in Singapore there are lot of more opportunity and really good place for strong career.

Also thing is Employers will offer Job only if I have Work Visa, I can get Work visa only if I have valid offer letter.

I am from India. I want to know which visa I need to get to go to Singapore and search for job and stay there. I also want to know if there is any  intermediate organisation who conduct interview to get job there.

Comment: This question was originally posted at http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/42843/294

Comment: Yes right, At there I got suggestion that here it is right place to post so I have posted here..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no visa specifically for looking for work**.  What you can do, though, is [apply for a visa as an ordinary tourist](http://www.mfa.gov.sg/content/mfa/overseasmission/london/visa_information/entryvisa_requirements.html), enter Singapore, and then look for work.

Comment: Ahh. I see..thanks for very helpful information..

Comment: @jpatokel, Hmm, what's the follow-up? What's the typical process after you've found a work (whil as a "tourist")?

Comment: @Pacerier Your new employer applies for an Employment Pass, which is usually processed in days, and then you start work.