# How can I get a visa to teach in Singapore?

Tags: visa, singapore, hong-kong

I am originally a tutor of high school (A - level, IB, AP, IGCSE ) maths and physics. However I am kind of tired of Hong Kong and want to relocate to Singapore to work as a tutor. The problem is, I am not Singaporean nor was I educated in Singapore. All I have is work experience in HK, graduating from a top university in HK.

What are the real chances of me obtaining an employment pass or visa for one of the academic centers in Singapore?

Comment: Probably slim to zero if you don’t meet the eligibility criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question in the title ("How can I get a visa to teach in Singapore") is — as noted by @Traveller in Comments — by satisfying the eligibility criteria.

The answer to the question in the last paragraph ("What are the real chances of getting a visa or employment pass?") is unknowable. No one here knows your complete history nor the information you might submit in a visa application; no one here is Singapore Immigration.

We also don't know whether you'd be successful in finding employment if you entered Singapore as a tourist. (See, for example, the answer to [this earlier question](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5826/visa-to-search-for-job-in-singapore?rq=1).)

Remember that SE sites (like this one) seek declarative answers, not opinions. The many variables and unknowables in your situation make this question unanswerable.